# Entropy(uncertainty) of imputed table with missing data?

Tags: missing-data, entropy, information-theory, imputation

[image: Original]
[image: Imputed]

Hello folks, I have a incomplete data(*A.Original*), *- represents missing value.
Imputed version of table A is shown in table *B.Imputed*. 
In table B, A(4,3) represents probability of having non-missing value for A.

 
My problem is to measure the entropy(uncertainty) of table B.


**How do we measure entropy(uncertainty) of table B?** 

Is there any method for this? 

*Any advice and criticism is highly appreciated :)*

Thanks.

Comment: What is the semantics of arguments `(3,2)`, in expressions `A(3,2)`, `B(3,2)`, etc ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question, In the question (4,3) is the probability of having non-missing value at A.

Comment: Are the columns independent of each other?   Are the individual rows independent of each other?   Do the `A` in "original table" imply all values are the same, or `missing`?  or do `A` represent possibly different values?  Entropy of any data is generally a function of probability distributions over all possible values, specifically  -E[log[X]] for a random variable X

Comment: Columns are not independent to each other. Table has individual tuples. Each value (A, B, ..) represents exactly same values.Basically Table A is imputed and each tuple has represented same in table B.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding your description of the table, then its entropy is actually zero:

Each row of the table is of the form `(A, B, C, D)`, and the values of `A` through `D` are always the same, then each tuple is always the same.  So you have a single element which never changes, and so its probability is `1`.  That kind of sequence has an entropy of zero.